# Start google play music via first chromecast found through intent from external app

Tags: android, android-intent, chromecast

Is there a way to start the google play music app from another app through an intent? If so is it also possible to tell it to look for any chromecasts in the local network and play via the first one found?

Context: I build a home automation prototype and want it to start playing music automatically in the living room once i get home. I can start the Receiver via good old remote controled power plugs and plug the chromecast in one of its hdmi input channels. so all i need is the phone to start streaming music to any chromecast found on the local network.

alternatively could i use this http://dpogue.ca/gmusic.html (is it even still working?) and write my own code that pulls my music library metadata from gmusic servers and then tell the cast to play a certain song/playlist directly from the music servers?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your goal is to start playing a certain song on Play Music on Chromecast from a different app. If so, that is not doable.

Comment: i would also accept if this is not possible, a way of playing a song from play music not using the android music app but writing my own code that will then delegate to cast  the URI from which the song could be found..

Comment: Google Play music doesn't have any official public APIs so the notion of a particular song (e.g. what id it has, etc) is not exposed. Since there is a user account involved, you cannot simply put together a URL and try to cast that, or anything else but using the Google Play Music app directly.